# Novaj vortoj/radikoj en PIV 2020

Tags: learning

Mi ĵus rimarkis ke la retejo de PIV (vortaro.net) ŝanĝiĝis kaj la enhavo nun devus esti tiu de PIV 2020.

Ĉu iu scias ĉu la aldonoj, forigoj, modifoj estas listitaj ie?

Answer (score 1):

Mi ne scias, ĉu ekzistas iu listo pri ŝanĝoj, sed oni ofte demandis, ĉu ekzistas iu listo pri mallongigoj kaj simboloj, kiujn oni uzas en PIV. Tiujn oni listigas sur la paĝo [*Klarigoj*](https://vortaro.net/#_klarigoj-diferencoj).

Ĉiuokaze Bertilo Wennergen prelegis pri PIV kaj faritaj ŝanĝoj, vd. la [filmeton](https://tubaro.aperu.net/v/ytb_hDeOz5Mbqps/) en Tubaro.

Aldono 2020-08-07:

Mi spektis la prelegon, en kiu Wennergren konstatas, ke PIV 2020 koncentriĝas pli al teknikaj ŝanĝoj ol al enhavaj. Li listigis jenajn vortojn, kiuj aŭ estas novaj aŭ havas aldonajn sencojn aŭ rimarkojn:

- [algio](https://vortaro.net/#algio_kdc)
- [alia](https://vortaro.net/#alia_kd)
- [didaktika](https://vortaro.net/#didaktika_kd)
- [Ĥanuko](https://vortaro.net/#%C4%A4anuko_kd)
- [kivio](https://vortaro.net/#kivio_kd)
- [Rodiso](https://vortaro.net/#Rodiso_kdc)